# R function - default value not inerpreted by the body

Tags: r, function, default

My problem concerns the following R function:

```
    but <- function(x, p = 0.95, FUN = mean, B = 1e4, smooth=FALSE, sd_smooth =1/sqrt(length(x)), ...)
{
  n <- length(x)
  bootmat <- replicate(B, sample(x, n, replace = TRUE))
  bootstat <- apply(bootmat, 2, FUN, ...)
  summary(bootstat); hist(bootstat)
  if (smooth) bootstat <- bootstat +rnorm(B, 0, sd_smooth)
  lo <- (1 - p)/2
  hi <- 1 - lo
  quantile(bootstat, c(lo, hi))
}
```

when I run

```
but(1:10)
```

it returns confidence intervals for a mean, as expected.
When I try:

```
but(1:10, median)
```

an error occurs:

```
Error in 1 - p : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

It seems that the default p (0.95) is not passed to the function body. I would be grateful for any hint about what is going wrong in my reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are many default parameters, and some of them are `...`, call them by name

```
but(1:10, FUN = median)
 2.5% 97.5% 
    3     8
```

-output

[image]